# How to launch new instance of chrome incognito window using HP UFT tool?

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am able to launch chrome using systemutil.run "chrome.exe" but I have no idea what command I have to use to launch chrome in incognito window.

```
systemutil.run "chrome.exe"
```

Chrome incognito should be launched in a new window which means it should launch in a new instance of chrome even if there is already an open window of chrome incognito.

Comment: @supputuri, tried this but not working. However the below one is working. Systemutl.run "chrome.exe", "-incognito http://www.google.co.in"

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the preference `--incognito` as part of systemutil run as shown below.

```
systemutil.run "chrome.exe --incognito"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Systemutil.Run  "chrome.exe", " -incognito " & URL
```

Comment: It is useful if you actually explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SystemUtil.Run "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",  " -incognito https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

This works for UFT one Version 2022.0.0.1004

Answer (score 0):

```
Systemutil.Run  "chrome.exe", " -incognito " & "https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

This works

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**